# while configuring ffmpeg i get the error "x264 not found"

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

i use mingw32 to compile ffmpeg with libx264. i use the following configuration:

*./configure   --enable-gpl  --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264*

and get the error

*ERROR: x264 not found*

i compiled x264 and x264 library (libx264.a) is located at /usr/lib/

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where are the includes and the .pc file and so the env variables include their paths?

Answer (score 0):

it took two days to succeed build ffmpeg with libx264 for Windows x64 (actually i compiled x264 and then ffmpeg).

i asked experts and one expert responded that there is a site with already prebuilt ffmpeg versions for Windows with libx264 and other codecs

https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/